# Robocopy copying from different drive

Tags: hard-drive, file-transfer, windows-11, robocopy

I am using robocopy to transfer files from an old laptop drive to an external drive because I believe the hard drive is close to failure. I ran the program with these arguments

```
robocopy D:\ E:\Toshiba1 /E /V /COPY:DAT /MT:32
```

I've ran the program overnight and it ran last night pulling files from the laptop drive without issue but as I came back in the morning to take a look at it the program started pulling files from my C: drive.
[Robocopy output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7S5my.png)
I know these files aren't from that D: drive because the user 13617 doesn't exist on that laptop and the folders Payments and Sandisk are unique to the current computer I'm using.

Is there a reason why this may have happened? Could this be prevented by using Richcopy instead?

[Folder for D drive, no Documents and Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YHWoG.png)

Comment: It looks like it's got confused by the symbolic links in the Documents folder. Try using the /xj option.

Comment: I wasn't aware of this issue but I'll take a look at it. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that these files do indeed exist on the `D:` drive and not on `C:`.

The folder `Documents and Settings` no longer exists on Windows 10/11,
so this seems to be an old backup.

You may exclude this folder by adding the following parameter to the command:

```
/xd "D:\Documents and Settings"
```

Or, if this is too inclusive :

```
/xd "D:\Documents and Settings\13617"
```

If this doesn't help, there might be a symbolic link on `D:`,
so add the parameter `/xj`, to exclude all junction points.
Don't use it if you're using junction points, as it will ignore all
of them.

Comment: This is indeed an older backup and after checking that folder doesn't exist (I added a pic in an edit to the OP) I'm led to believe that they are junctions. I'll remove them and see what happens. Thank you.

Comment: So i tried running it again and it got stuck on a similar issue. /xj should've helped but it ran into an infinite loop again.

Comment: I would suggest doing `chkdsk` without `/f`, just to check. If you decide to use `/f`, save first as much data as you can.